# Symfony 2.8: how to upload an image from URL soruce?

Tags: file, symfony, file-upload, upload

How are you? First, sorry about my english :(

I'm triying to upload a file from a URL source like **https://www.somedomain/somefolder/someimage.jpg** but I'm getting some troubles...

I get this error when I'm triying to set **`$myFile->setFile('url')`**:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyBundle\Entity\File::setFile() must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given

I've also tried through **`$content = get_file_contents('url')`** and then **`$myFile->setFile($content)`**, but this returns the same error.

On the other hand, it's not a problem if I upload the file with an inputfile box in a form. But I cannot do it by indicating only one URL source (for a CronJob, by the way).

I've read the documentation about Files on Symfony, but I can't get success :(

Can anyone help me with this issue, please?

Thanks a lot! Greetings from Barcelona!! :)

Comment: @Franck Gamess thanks for the edition!

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this issue you can do this:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

$file = new UploadedFile('url', 'name of the file');
$myFile->setFile($file);
```

Take a look at [UploadedFile](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html)

Be sure to provide the correct path to the path. Not sure it will work like this because you want to set the UploadedFile without uploading the file through an input file and without submitting the form. Have a try.

Comment: HI! I've tried this, but I get this error: (i've tried it with the google logo hahaha):

The file "https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" does not exist

Comment: You have an error because is_file('https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') return false. Try to use a file which is in your filesystem. Better use an absolute url like /var/www/file/path